# Unicode/Collation Issue in Openrowset SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation, unicode-string

My CSV has text like this:

```
Côté fenêtres,
carré
```

I'm trying to open this CSV file using openrowset in SQL Server  like below:-

```
select * from openrowset(BULK 'C:\Import_Orders\Files\PO.csv', 
FORMATFILE = 'C:\Import_Orders\Format\Cust_441211.fmt.txt') as PO
```

But the result is like this:

```
C+¦t+¬ fen+¬tres,
Carr+¬
```

How can I tackle this issue? Let me know if I need to add anything more to this question.

SQL Version -
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU29-GDR) (KB5014553) - 14.0.3445.2 (X64)

This is the format file:-

```
11.0
8
1       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      1       PARTNO    ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      2       CODE   ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      3       PRICEKG ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      4       FOOTKG    ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      5       LENGTH    ""
6       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      6       QTY   ""
7       SQLCHAR             0       250      "|"      7       COLOR ""
8       SQLCHAR             0       250      "\r\n"   8       TOTKG ""
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Noted. I have added select query into the question. Thanks!

Comment: Please add to your question the following details: (1) format file, (2) SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) You can try to add an additional parameter `CODEPAGE = '65001'` to specify a code page to support UNICODE characters.

(2) Use may try to use SQLNCHAR data type instead of SQLCHAR in the format file. For a text file you should always specify SQLCHAR for all fields, unless you have a Unicode file in in UTF‑16 encoding in which case you should use SQLNCHAR.

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM openrowset(BULK 'C:\Import_Orders\Files\PO.csv', 
FORMATFILE = 'C:\Import_Orders\Format\Cust_441211.fmt.txt',
CODEPAGE = '65001') as PO;
```

Comment: I did try the second option before but it returned an error. Format file-
```
1       SQLNCHAR            0       2000      "|"      1       PARTNO ""
```
but got the error as:-
```
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (PARTNO).
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 78
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 78
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Comment: Adding codepage = "65001" worked! Thank you Khabinsky.

Comment: Glad to hear the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.